# ajax php with category search

Tags: php, ajax, search

Hello I am developing an ajax php search. It will search through the database accross multiple tables when someone types. My question is that i need it to bring up a name like if someone types the name Apple tv i want it to bring up do you want the category or the specific product?. How can i do that?

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
//Database values
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "tool";
$user = "root";
$password = "root";
$database = new mysqli();

$database->connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);

//Kill website if database connection fails
if($database->connect_errno) {
die("Database connection failed.");
}

//Connect to the database
//Clean user input
$search = $database->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
$search = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $search);
$search = "'%".$_POST['search']."%'";

$query = "SELECT * FROM brands WHERE braname LIKE $search ORDER by braname ASC LIMIT 5";

if($results = $database->query($query)){
while ($player = $results->fetch_assoc()){
echo "<div class='col-sm-4' id='adjust-Searchbox'>" . "<a href=\"users/e-commerceTemplateSingleBrand.php?braid=".$player['braid']."\">" . "<p>" . $player["braname"] . "</p>" . "<img style='width:100%; height:50px;' src=\" uploads/".$player['braimg']."\">" . "</a>" . "</div>"

;
}
}else{
die("Database connection failed.");
}

$search = $database->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
$search = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $search);
$search = "'%".$_POST['search']."%'";

$query = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE name LIKE $search ORDER by name ASC LIMIT 5";

if($results = $database->query($query)){
while ($player = $results->fetch_assoc()){
echo "<div class='col-sm-4' id='adjust-Searchbox'>" . "<p>" . $player["name"] . "</p>" . "<img style='width:100%; height:50px;' src=\" uploads/".$player['proimg']."\">" . "</br>" . "</div>";
}
}else{
die("Database connection failed.");
}
```

Comment: Use `onkeyup` method on an `INPUT` form item to call an Ajax request to your php code sending the search value in `$_POST['search']`, I suggest when calling a Javascript function that executes an Ajax call `onkeyup` or `onchange` you should have a timer of a second or two, that delays the execution of the Ajax call, this time should reset every time a new call to the function is pressed to avoid excessive Ajax calls.

Comment: My search works by you write something e.g. Apple TV. once a user types that it will ask them do you mean category or product. If they click on category it will come up with a list of the products in that category. If product then it will show that individual product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the search text field

```
<input onkeyup="do_search();" type="text" value="" id="search_string">
```

Then add your javascript to call the ajax

```
function do_search() {
$('#the_div_to_show_ajax_return').html('Please wait ...');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "yourcode.php",
data: {search: $('#search_string').val()}
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    $('#the_div_to_show_ajax_return').html(msg);
});
}
```

Also make sure you have a div ready for the results

```
<div id="the_div_to_show_ajax_return"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, now i get three results at the same time. How do i get it to show only one result rather then two